# Check if a date is between 2 dates in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have 4 strings values:

```
Dim start As String,end As String,day1 As String,day2 As String
start="15/01/2015"
end="25/03/2015"
day1="20/02/2015"
day2="18/04/2015"
```

I would like to have a function which test if a day(day1 or day2) is between 2 dates(start and end), for example, it returns me true for day1, and false for day2.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You cannot use `end` as variable name, it's a reserved word of the compiler. Apart for this, you only need to define the variable as `Date` rather than string, and make a simple comparison such as `day1 < yourDate` (will return true or false)

Answer (score 3):

```
Function BetweenDates(startDate As String, endDate As String, testDate As String) As Boolean
    BetweenDates = IIf(CDate(testDate) > CDate(startDate) And CDate(testDate) <= CDate(endDate), True, False)
End Function
```

Comment: it could be simplified to: BetweenDates = CDate(testDate) > CDate(startDate) And CDate(testDate) <= CDate(endDate)

which should make even more clear that the use of a function is quite an overkill